# Qt isOpen method false value MySQL

Tags: mysql, qt, connection

I have a MySQL database, which i created in Workbench. I can easily connect to it using php code:

```
<?php 
    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 3306;
    $socket = "";
    $user = "hate";
    $password = "88005553535";
    $dbname = "galleries_db";
    $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
    echo "DONE!";
?>
```

But when I'm trying to connect to my DB with Qt like this:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(3306);
db.setDatabaseName("galleries_db");
db.setUserName("hate");
db.setPassword("88005553535");
db.open();
if(!db.isOpen()) {
    ui->label->setText("-");
    qDebug() << "Error: "<<  db.lastError() << " " << db.lastError().text();
}
else
    ui->label->setText("+");
```

I always get false value returned by *isOpen* method. And in stream I have:

> Error:  QSqlError("", "", "")   " "

May be problem in MySQL driver for Qt ? Or there is something else ?
Will appriciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be:

```
if(db.isOpen())
```

Not:

```
if(!db.isOpen())
```

Actually it is very silly mistake. *isOpen* always returned me true value, and I made it false by myself.